# USB Stick not showing up properly despite it being detected

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, windows-explorer

I have a 8GB USB Stick. When connecting to my PC it gets detected and shows up in the Device Manager like any other USB Drive. But in Explorer it doesn't show up, there is however a drive Letter added, but when clicking it just says that I should insert a USB Drive, and when rightclicking it also can't be formatted.

Is this just a problem that it isn't mounted, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Open [Windows Disk Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management) to check the USB flash drive.

- Insert the USB drive.
- Press Windows and enter *diskmg*.
- Select *diskmgmt.msc*.
- The USB drive should be listed as a separate disk with at a "Healthy (Active, Primary Partition", likely [formatted as FAT32 or exFAT](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-format-usb-drive-using-using-fat-fat32-ntfs-exfat/).

If there is no healthy partition, you can try formatting the USB drive.

- Right-click on the drive in *Windows Disk Management*.
- Select *Format...* and follow the prompts to format exFAT or FAT32. **N.B.** This will delete all data currently on the drive. Be *very* careful to select the correct drive!

If that doesn't fix the issue, then the drive has deceased. Dispose of it responsibly.